# Operation_Precedence_in_Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, operators, operator-precedence

Could someone explain to me about operator precedence? For eg. Modulo(%), integer division(//), exponential(**) What comes first, second, third and so on. Also please help me with the output of the following code and with step by step explanation:

```
print(8 % 3 ** 4 // 3 + 2)
```

I coudnt understand about Operator Precedence. Please help

Comment: This article may help you [precedence-associativity](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity)

Comment: Normal mathematical operators have the same precedence as they do in algebra. Braces-exponent-....etc:

Comment: But, could you also explain the question mentioned.

Comment: @JayantAgarwal. did you understand the answer.

Comment: Thank you @Kungfupanda for the answer. I have a doubt how is 8%81 = 8?

Comment: @JayantAgarwal. modulo operation is nothing but giving remainder as output.

Comment: How is the remainder of 8 % 81 = 8?

Comment: @JayantAgarwal. if you do 3%2---when you divide 3 with 2 it gives 2 as quotient and 1 as remainder. but when you do 8%81 -----81 cant divide 8 . as 81 is a higher number . it gives the dividend as remainder.

Comment: Ohh i didnt know about dividend being the remainder. Thank you very much

Comment: @JayantAgarwal. coool. when you do modulo operation. if the divisor is greater than dividend. it simply gives dividend as output as it cant divide lower number with higher number.

Comment: @Kungfupanda Thank you very much. Looks like I learned something new!! Awesome!

Comment: @JayantAgarwal.great .keep learning and keep exploring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the Operator Precedence from parentheses to logical or operator.
if you have parentheses and logical or operator in your expression.
parentheses will be evaluated first and logical or operator will be evaluated last due to order of operator precedence.

Associativity is when you have operators of same precedence.then it evaluates from left to right .
for example(2*3//3):if you have multiplication * and floor division // in your expression. then multiplication is evaluated first then it goes for floor division as they both have same precedence.it follows associativity
evaluating from left to right.

```
•   Operators   •   Meaning
•   ()  •   Parentheses
•   **  •   Exponent
•   +x, -x, ~x  •   Unary plus, Unary minus, Bitwise NOT
•   *, /, //, % •   Multiplication, Division, Floor division, Modulus
•   +, -    •   Addition, Subtraction
•   <<, >>  •   Bitwise shift operators
•   &   •   Bitwise AND
•   ^   •   Bitwise XOR
•   |   •   Bitwise OR
•   ==, !=, >, >=, <, <=, is, is not, in, not in    •   Comparisons, Identity, Membership operators
•   not •   Logical NOT
•   and •   Logical AND
•   or  •   Logical OR




print(8 % 3 ** 4 // 3 + 2)---exponent is evaluated first 
print(8%81//3+2)----modulo and floor division have same precedence.so it evaluates from left to right . first evaluates modulo.
print(8//3+2)----then goes for floor division 
print(2+2)-----then addition operation
so the output is 4.
```